# How to resolve TypeError: dispatch_model() got an unexpected keyword argument 'offload_index'?

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

After running the following code:

```
import torch
from accelerate import infer_auto_device_map, init_empty_weights
from transformers import AutoConfig, AutoModelForCausalLM


config = AutoConfig.from_pretrained("facebook/opt-13b")
with init_empty_weights():
    model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_config(config)

device_map = infer_auto_device_map(model, no_split_module_classes=["OPTDecoderLayer"], dtype="float16")


model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
    "facebook/opt-13b", 
    device_map=device_map,
    offload_folder="offload",
    offload_state_dict=True,
    torch_dtype=torch.float16)
```

I end up with the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_23/3733710460.py in <module>
      4     offload_folder="offload",
      5     offload_state_dict=True,
----> 6     torch_dtype=torch.float16)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/models/auto/auto_factory.py in from_pretrained(cls, pretrained_model_name_or_path, *model_args, **kwargs)
    463             model_class = _get_model_class(config, cls._model_mapping)
    464             return model_class.from_pretrained(
--> 465                 pretrained_model_name_or_path, *model_args, config=config, **hub_kwargs, **kwargs
    466             )
    467         raise ValueError(

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/modeling_utils.py in from_pretrained(cls, pretrained_model_name_or_path, *model_args, **kwargs)
   2527         # Dispatch model with hooks on all devices if necessary
   2528         if device_map is not None:
-> 2529             dispatch_model(model, device_map=device_map, offload_dir=offload_folder, offload_index=offload_index)
   2530 
   2531         if output_loading_info:

TypeError: dispatch_model() got an unexpected keyword argument 'offload_index'
```

I'm trying to load a large model from hugging face, and to do that, I split the weights into the GPUs from Kaggle. I don't understand exactly what is going on here, and how to deal with this issue.

Comment: Have you verified that all of the related packages are up to date? From the HuggingFace documentation it looks like the offload_index parameter was added to dispatch model in version 0.15.0

Comment: Any solution? I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please try updating your **accelerate** package, for example

```
pip install accelerate==0.18.0
```

Comment: That didn't help ☹

Answer (score 1):

first add these packages :

```
!pip install accelerate>=0.18.0 transformers[torch]==4.25.1
!pip install -q datasets loralib sentencepiece
!pip -q install git+https://github.com/huggingface/peft.git
!pip -q install bitsandbytes
```

then try commenting the

```
device_map='auto'
```

In my case it worked

[image]